# getting error The multi-part identifier "e.EpVisitCount" could not be bound. in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on converting mysql query to sql server, but when i run the query it gives me error `The multi-part identifier "e.EpVisitCount" could not be bound.` ,  here i have posted my both query can you please look into it, why it gives me error in sql server ?

Mysql Query(Working Fine) :

```
UPDATE
                tb_EpVisitRange as v left JOIN tb_Episode as e ON (v.company_id = e.CustID) AND (v.CMW = e.CMW)
                SET
                e.EpVisitCount = If(PayerType='NonEp',0,If(LUPA=1,0,v.High)),
                e.VisitAlert = If( e.TotVisits > v.High,1,NULL) 
                where  UploadID = '23'
```

SQl Query(Getting Error) :

```
UPDATE v
SET
e.EpVisitCount = IIF(PayerType='NonEp',0,IIF(LUPA=1,0,v.High)),
e.VisitAlert = IIF( e.TotVisits > v.High,1,NULL) 
FROM tb_EpVisitRange  v
JOIN tb_Episode as e ON (v.company_id = e.CustID) AND (v.CMW = e.CMW)
where  UploadID = '613'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to update `e` rather than `v`.  So, you might try:

```
UPDATE e
    SET EpVisitCount = (CASE WHEN PayerType = 'NonEp' THEN 0
                             WHEN LUPA = 1 THEN 0
                             ELSE v.High
                        END),
        VisitAlert = (CASE WHEN e.TotVisits > v.High THEN 1 END) 
FROM tb_Episode e JOIN
     tb_EpVisitRang v 
     ON v.company_id = e.CustID AND v.CMW = e.CMW
WHERE UploadID = '613';
```

Notes:

- The problem appears to be the table alias used for the update.
- SQL Server only allows updating one table in a statement.  There is no need to qualify the column names for the `SET`.
- Use `CASE` for conditions.  It is the ANSI standard and supported by almost all database.
- This is especially true for nested expressions.  `CASE` supports multiple conditions.
- You are updating `e`, so I made that the first table in the `FROM` clause.  I find that logic easier to follow.
- You should qualify `UploadId`.